# Setting a views height is throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: android, view, height

Hello i am trying to set a views height but its throwing a null pointer exception at the second line.

Im actually trying to add a header to a list activity. For that my code is:

```
View header= (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customheader, null);
getListView.addHeaderView(header);
header.getLayoutParams().height=(int)55; //This line is throwing a null pointer exception
setListAdapter(adapter);


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(-1, 55);
    View header= (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customheader, null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);
    getListView().setCacheColorHint(0);
    getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.patterns);
    setListAdapter(new Settingsadapter(this, menu));
    header.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Exception:
E/AndroidRuntime(504): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer, it helps other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating your view, but not adding it anywhere.  To set the height, the view needs to be in the application.

If you are trying to retrive part of your existing layout, you need to do this:

```
View header = (View)findViewById(R.layout.customheader); 
header.getLayoutParams().height=55;
```

Comment: oh alright. i was trying to add a header to a list view using an existing layout file customheader which i am using in other activities as well

Answer (score 1):

make sure in ur customheader ,height as 0 or some values don't enter wrapcontent,fillparent ,matchparent values...

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(urWidth, 55);
    View  header= (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customheader, null);

    header.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: i edited my program but im getting a classCastException with this code

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding it to a listView as a header , you will need the LayoutParams to be AbsListView.LayoutParams

```
AbsListView.LayoutParams params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(urWidth, 55);
View  header= (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customheader, null);
header.setLayoutParams(params);
listView.addHeader(header);
```